# Extract array of limbs from mpf_class (GMP)

Tags: c++, gmp, arbitrary-precision

Given an mpf_class variable how exactly do I extract the array of limbs associated to the mantissa? For example I want to do some bitwise operations on one of the limbs. I tried reading the GMP documentation however I ended up a bit confused.

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/Float-Internals.html , but you are not supposed to do that. Actually, using mpf_t  or mpf_class in any new code doesn't sound like a good idea, better use the library MPFR (also based on GMP).